# How can I change List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>(); to sql?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have C# code with mysql connection ,but I dont know mysql
How can i change

```
List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
```

to sql?

```
WriteLog(Exception ex) 
{ 
    SQLHelper sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(); 
    List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>(); 
    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_DateTime", DateTime.Now));  
    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_ErrorMessage", ex.Message)); 
    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_ErrorStack", ex.StackTrace)); 
    sqlHelper.executeSP<int>(parameters, "InsertLog"); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by _change it to sql_ of your `List` of `MySqlParameter` exactly? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Phrase "Change *some C# code* to MySQL" has no sense at all.

Comment: I thin you would still need to know what type of command you would need to execute. Is it a `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc.

Comment: s ,,,thank you for ur replay

Comment: below is my code..iwant to use this in c# and sQl is this possible or can i change any thing

public void WriteLog(Exception ex)
{
    SQLHelper sqlHelper = new SQLHelper();
    List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_DateTime", DateTime.Now));
    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_ErrorMessage", ex.Message));
    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_ErrorStack", ex.StackTrace));

    sqlHelper.executeSP<int>(parameters, "InsertLog");
}

Comment: I have extracted the code from your comment and applied it to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are calling invokes and executes a stored procedure. The only thing which the application is doing, other than the invocation is the provision of parameters.

Long story short, the actual SQL queries are not within the application itself, thus there is nothing to change.